# Service worker is not working without reloading page after server start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

In my single-page application in ReactJS, I use service worker. In order to work properly Service worker, after starting the server,

> It is necessary to refresh the page.

is there any ways to solve this problem so that the user does not have to reload the page?

Comment: Can you elaborate (* it is necessary to reload the page every time*). How does a properly working service worker requires it?

Comment: I started the server and launched my application. The service worker will work only if after starting the server, reload the page. With the help of a service worker, I will send a push notification.

Comment: see "updating the service worker" in https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle   its quite long because lifecycle around updates is complex. there are ways to avoid the waits for updates when the SW version changes.

Comment: this one also good background  : https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68